# Laravel 4 Model Relationship not working properly. Can't access related column from Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

lets say I have three Models: Chapter, Book, Author.

> A Book hasMany Chapter && Chapter belongsTo Book.
>
> Author hasMany Book && Book belognsTo Author.

That means, that the ChapterTable has a book_id and the BookTable has an author_id.

Now I want to count all the chapters, from a specific author. How would I go about it using Blade?

Here is what I am thinking about:

```
  $chapters = Book::where('author_id', $author)->with('chapters')->get();
  $chapters = lists('chapter_title');
```

But those lines are not working properly, because the chapters are saved as an array inside the book_array and I am not able to access the chapters directly as suggested in "lists('chapter_title');"

Of course a solution would be, to give every chapter Table an author_id, and then I just could do:

```
 $chapters = Chapter::where('author_id', $author)->get();
 $chapters = lists('chapter_title');
```

I know this would work, but isn't there the possibility to get above results, without having an authors id on my chapters table?

Regards,

George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Eloquent` way using `hasManyThrough`:

```
// Author model
public function chapters()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Chapter', 'Book');
}

// then
$author->chapters()->count(); // single query for a single author
```

---

In order to eager load the count for multiple authors you need for example this:

```
// Author model
public function chaptersCount()
{
    return $this->chapters()->selectRaw('count(*) as aggregate')->groupBy('author_id');
}

public function getChaptersCountAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('chaptersCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('chaptersCount');

    return $this->getRelation('chaptersCount')->first()->aggregate;
}
```

Then:

```
$authors = Author::with('chaptersCount')->get();
$authors->first()->chaptersCount;

// or for a single author
$author->chaptersCount; // load the relation if needed
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look at this http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

```
$chapters = Book::has('author', $author)->with('chapters')->get();
$chapters = lists('chapter_title');
```

and for your chapters you can access them like `Book->chapters`